# Compare instanceof with a generic class, for Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, generics, fragment

I am trying to create a generic function to attach the Fragments. I wanted to call this function whenever I wanted to attach any Fragment that I created.

```
    private <MyFragment extends Fragment> void attachFragmentOnBotNavClick(MyFragment fragment, String tag){
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) instanceof MyFragment) {
        fragment = (MyFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, tag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

[image]

> Error is **Class or Array is expected**

Comment: Can you add complete code?

Comment: This is the complete code for replacing a fragment. I am just trying to make it generic

Comment: You can see this article https://www-androidhive-info.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/amp/?usqp=mq331AQQKAGYAfSC6uq70bKhXrABIA%3D%3D&amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2017%2F12%2Fandroid-working-with-bottom-navigation%2F how a function is used to replace fragments